# How to update data to md-table?

Tags: forms, angular

I am developing web app with Angular 4, but I have a problem because I don't understand how to access to new data in my `md-table`

I have reproduced the same example for my application

https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/material-examples/table-http

I have a component with a `form` and `table-http` component, in my table-httpComponent I have @Input field with variables sent from my form, but when I call table-http no problem, this receive data from form correctly and rendered data, but when I modify fields in form and I press button (submit) I can't render `table-http` with new `@Input date` field sent.

In my template component I have this

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
  <div>
    <md-input-container>
      <input
        mdInput
        [mdDatepicker]="pickerInit"
        placeholder="Fecha inicial"
        name="init"
        #init="ngModel"
        ngModel
        required>
      <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="pickerInit"></button>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-datepicker #pickerInit></md-datepicker>
  </div>
  <div >
    <button md-raised-button>Buscar</button>
  </div>
</form>
<http-table *ngIf=active [date]=date></http-table>
```

This is my `onSubmit` method

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
  this.active = false;
  if (!f.value["init"]) {
    alert("Ingrese la fecha de inicio.");
    return;
  }
  this.date = this.localISOTime(f.value["init"]);
  this.active = true;
  console.log("Form values -> ", f.value); //Here my data exists without problem
}
```

In my `table-http` component I have declared my field `@Input() date: Date`

When I press the button for the first time there is not a problem, `table-http` rendering correct data, but when I press the button for the second time `http-table` not reload with new data.

I don't understand why don't reload with new data.

**UPDATE**

Here I add my plunker, in short, my problem is based on that when selecting a date for example and pressing the button (press a second time to advance, this in my real component does not happen so do not worry about it), by Console is printed twice the same date, assuming that date is used in my service to get the new data, if I change the date and press the button again do not reprint this data and never update my table.

https://plnkr.co/edit/80955I8GGis25hbpPBz5?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understood your issue, what you mean is that when date is changed in parent, the http-request isn't refired upon change.

Actually you don't need the `OnInit` in the child, as we don't need to fire anything when component is initialized. What you want to do, is to fire when child gets a date input. So what we can then do, is to utilize `ngOnChanges` life cycle hook, as that watches for changes in `@Input`. So you can remove the `OnInit` in child and instead do:

```ts
ngOnChanges() {
  console.log("onchanges -> ", this.date);
  this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleHttpDao(this.http, this.date)
  this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase);   
  this.ref.detectChanges()
}
```

Apparently there was also some change detection issue at least in plunker, so we added `ChangeDetectorRef` and manually trigger change detection with `detectChanges()`.

```ts
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(...., private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

In the plunker you can now see the console log `fired!` in the http-request whenever the date is changed.

Your plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/VQ6aKVeJfWy3S8JkD7YL?p=preview

Comment: Hopefully I diagnosed you issue correctly and that the above solution works for you! :)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear we got a solution for you! :)